# How do I get web workers to work in GWT?

Tags: gwt, web-worker

I've searched and searched and I can't find any clear examples online.  I'd like to do this as easily and simply as possible.  Can anyone provide information on how to use web workers in GWT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check out http://code.google.com/p/speedtracer/source/browse/trunk/src/client/ui/src/com/google/gwt/webworker/